Interpret the $\Delta X$ in $\text{log det}(I+X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{log}(1+\lambda_{i})$
A textbook I am reading in its derivation states that (We are on $\mathbb{R}$)
$$\text{log det}(I+X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{log}(1+\lambda_{i})$$
where $X$ is a n-by-n positive definite matrix (so $X^{-1/2}$ is the unique positive square root of the inverse of $X$), $\Delta X$ is, quoting the text, a "small" matrix of the same size as $X$ (This is all the text has to say about $\Delta X$),  and $\lambda_{i}$ is the ith eigenvalues of $X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$. The text goes on to states that since $\Delta X$ is small, $\lambda_{i}$ are small.
(The above is part of the text finding $\text{log det}Z$, where $Z = X+\Delta X$, and $\Delta X$ is "small".)
I have two questions with the statement:

What exactly are the assumptions here for $\Delta X$?

Clearly it is not enough for it to be "small". Making it positive semi-definite seems to be too strict, but the equation would then make sense: Since "$\Delta X$ being positive semi-definite $\iff X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$ being positive semi-definite", $X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$ would indeed have n eigenvalues (including geometric multiplicity), as stated by the summation on the right. Also, all eigenvales are nonnegative, so no problems with the log. But I feel like there can be other looser, more "useful" requirements (self-adjoint?) that also works with this equation.
That "there exists $n$ $\lambda_{i}$ (including geometric multiplicity)" is equivalent to "$X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$ being diagonalizable". So, I am concerned with the fact that randomly choosing $\Delta X$ would make $X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$ not diagonalizable, and thus not have $n$ eigenvalues including geometric multiplicity. Is this concern valid?

Why would $\lambda_{i}$ be small when $\Delta X$ is small?

The text does not specify what norm to use on the vector space of symmetric matrices. If I assume it uses the Frobenius norm, I still can't see why $\lambda_{i}$ should be small.
This post ends up longer than I expected. I may have erred in my thought process and would appreciate any correction or inquiry for clarification.

FYI the book is "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe. This is on page 641.

$\Delta X$ does not need to be positive definite. In fact the real restriction here is that $|X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}|< 1$ and this can indeed be obtained for a small enough $\Delta X$, since the norm is linear in $c$ if you multiply $\Delta X$ by $c$. (I am assuming it is symmetric though)

Equality holds as long as the principal branch of complex logarithm is chosen on both sides and $I+X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2}$ has not any real non-positive eigenvalue. These two conditions per se depend neither on the smallness of $\Delta X$ nor on the diagonalisability of $\Delta X$. However, the smallness of $\Delta X$ does guarantee that the latter condition holds, because $\rho(X^{-1/2}\Delta XX^{-1/2})=\rho(X^{-1}\Delta X)\le|X^{-1}\Delta X|\le|X^{-1}||\Delta X|$ for all submultiplicative norms.

@Exodd Could you elaborate on why having $||X^{-1/2}\Delta X X^{-1/2}||<1$ would allow $I+X^{-1/2}\Delta X X^{-1/2}$ to have n eigenvalues counting geometric multiplicity?
Just to be sure, am I infering correctly that since the summation uses $\lambda_{i}$, where $i=1,..,n$, this means $I+X^{-1/2}\Delta X X^{-1/2}$ has to be diagonalizable?

I am supposing $\Delta X$ symmetric, because otherwise there is no guarantee that the log-det formula you use actually holds

@Exodd Ahh, so I misunderstood. It is because $\Delta X$ is symmetric that $X^{1/2}\Delta X X^{1/2}$ is diagonalizable, not the $||X^{1/2}\Delta X X^{1/2}||<1$
